# How to get the Month from date string in sql server

Tags: android, date, date-difference

As stated in the Title of the question , i have different days in different accounts, How to get the date part of these

Comment: how is the format ?  mena mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: How can someone with 2k reputation post such a question? Consider adding more details and improving formatting. Vast majority of your questions was improved by other users. You should learn from those edits..

Answer (score 1):

Just change the date formats below depending on your date format:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
    Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str); 
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM"); // you can use 'dd' for date
    return df.format(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```